# Select element inaccessible after relatively positioned element in Chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser

I'm seeing strange behavior in Chrome (v21.0.1180.89), but it works fine in FireFox.
Here's the HTML:

```
<div style="position:relative;text-align:right;width:500px;height:100px;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x100"></img>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></img>
    <div>foo</div>
</div>
<div style="height:50px;">bar</div>
<select>
    <option value="1">One xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Only in Chrome, the select can't get focus when you click on it (but you can tab to it).

If you increase the height of the 'bar' div to 100px, so that the select appears below the 100x100 image, then you can click on it.

Is this expected and Chrome is behaving correctly, or is FF just being more tolerant?

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awilliams47/xjuae/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xjuae/2/

z-index: -1

The upper div is expanding over top of the select.  That's unintended behaviour, but here's a fix.

Comment: Unfortunately, the real page has a ton of other stuff in that div, so I'd have to position them and z stack them appropriately. Doable, but a pain. If I absolutely position the image within the div, it doesn't make it expand: http://jsfiddle.net/awilliams47/xjuae/6/

Comment: I ended up using `position:absolute` on the img within the div. While I didn't use your solution, you did answer my question about browser behavior and got me thinking along the correct path, so I accepted your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` element expands to overlap the `select` element, use:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

in your css for the `div` to counter-act it.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xjuae/3/

Comment: Unfortunately, the real page has a ton of clickable stuff in that div, so that won't work easily. I'm also not sure if this is an issue in IE, which I don't believe supports `pointer-events`.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `position:relative` on the top div all is well.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xjuae/5/)**

Comment: Yes, but I need that for the actual layout. The fiddle is abbreviated code.